# Why do I get this error in SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml()? "The specified field name is too long"

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting an error when I call SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml().

Why is that?  Here is the string I'm using:

> "<Field Type='Note' Required='FALSE' NumLines='6' RichText='FALSE' Sortable='FALSE' ID='{aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa}' StaticName='tempField' Name='tempField' />"

Naturally, I'm using a different guid.

EDIT: MOSS2007/WSS3.0
EDIT2: Rephrased as question.

Comment: You need to elaborate a question.

Comment: This is not a question, this is an answer for reference (as i see it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot the DisplayName attribute.  The following works:

> "<Field Type='Note' Required='FALSE' NumLines='6' RichText='FALSE' Sortable='FALSE' ID='{aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa}' DisplayName='tempField' StaticName='tempField' Name='tempField' />"